# R How to separate simple function like“-10.81+2.02” in to numbers eg.“-10.81”and “2.02”?

Tags: regex, r

my data is like:
-10.81+2.02
47-7
what i need to do is separate each one into two numbers and add them together
eg. separate -10.81+2.02 into "-10.81" and "2.02" and then add them together so i can get -8.79
separate 47-7 into 47 and -7, and add them together to get 40.

many many thanks!

Comment: You appear to have materially asked the same question three times in the last hour. Please don't post duplicates!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strsplit` to break up the string into pieces and then `eval` and `parse` to evaluate the mathematical expressions:

```
dat <- "-10.81+2.02 47-7"
sapply(strsplit(dat, " ")[[1]], function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))
# -10.81+2.02        47-7 
#       -8.79       40.00
```

If you unlike the names on the vector you can instead do:

```
unname(sapply(strsplit(dat, " ")[[1]], function(x) eval(parse(text=x))))
# [1] -8.79 40.00
```